# Running a simple python flask application using .cfg config files. I can't seem to return the config values, getting a keying error with them

Tags: python, flask

The aim of this program is just to return the values that are passed from a .cfg configuration file called 'defaults.cfg'.

I totally understand what should be getting passed here and to be honest the code for all intents and purposes is copied from an exercise, but it fails with a 'Keying error: (value)' (all values give the keying error, it's just whatever is first) and I don't know why. I've been unable to find a solution online and the code is the same in principle as a friend's more complicated program running a proper web application and his works just fine.

Apparently using capitals for the config keys is a thing and I've done that and I'm sure I have all the necessary libraries/binaries installed.

I'm doing this on Bash on Windows on Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance for any consideration.

***default.cfg***

```
[config]
DEBUG = True
IP_ADDRESS = 0.0.0.0
PORT = 5000
```

***configuration.py***

```
import ConfigParser

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def root():
    return "Sup! Hollerin' at ya from the configuration testing app"

@app.route('/WTF/')
def tellMeh():
    return app.config['PORT']

@app.route('/config/')
def config():
    str = []
    str.append(app.config['DEBUG'])
    str.append('port:'+app.config['PORT'])
    str.append('ip_address:'+app.config['IP'])
    return '\t'.join(str)

def init(app):
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    try:
        config_location = "etc/defaults.cfg"
        config.read(config_location)

        app.config['DEBUG'] = config.get("config", "DEBUG")
        app.config['IP'] = config.get("config", "IP_ADDRESS")
        app.config['PORT'] = config.get("config", "PORT")

        print "Succesfully read configs from: ", config_location
    except:
        print "Couldn't read configs from: ", config_location

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init(app)
    app.run(
        host=app.config['IP'],
        port=int(app.config['PORT']))
```

Comment: Also, I can get 'app.config['DEBUG']' to return but I think this is because it's a value that's held by default, rather than the value I created. See : http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/

Comment: Are you sure that `config.read(config_location)` is succeeding?  Check the return value.  The working directory when the app is run may be such that `etc/defaults.cfg` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get different behavior from that code depending on how you invoke it.

`FLASK_APP=configuration.py flask run` will skip the section at the bottom where `init(app)` is called

`python configuration.py` will run that section, calling `init(app)`.

You might wish to move the call to `init()` to right below `app = Flask(...)`.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have been what was happening. I was running it with 'python -m flask run'. I assumed that as I hadn't set the IP and port in the commandline and the thing was running then it must have been getting the values from the .cfg